# Area of a square cut by a line, identifying the smaller side

Tags: area

I have a grid with a path running through it.  Within each of the grid squares, where the path intersects, I want to determine which side of the current grid has the smaller area.  I was hoping there was a clever way to do this by measuring up (or down) from the grid corners, to where the path intersects, and calculating if they crossed more than 50% of the grid, but I'm not clever enough cuz whatever I try fails.  So I was wondering if anyone could suggest the proper route to do it this for each square will have a different shape.

I'm assuming I'll have to break each grid into "shapes", and then calculate the area of the shapes; but I was hoping not to have to go that route.  In my case I'm writing a javascript program to automate this, so having to determine the shapes programmatically will also be a challenge.  Thanks!

Here's a pic of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Edit: BTW I do know the x,y positions of all path intersections and I know the grid points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Valerie:

Does this figure help?

[image]

Just take the average of the $y$ (vertical) values at the left value of $x$ and right value of $x$--the green points.  If this average is above the squares midpoint, then the larger area is below.

Comment: It does thanks.  I guess with the formula for calculating the line I can do this.

Comment: Okay got it.  Will try this and it makes sense!  Yay.

Comment: Worked great and it was so easy.  Exactly what I needed thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to measure anything.

The straight line is given by an equation of the form
$$
ax + by = c.
$$
If you use the center of a grid square as $(x,y)$ you will have an inequality (unless the center lies on the line).
$$
ax + by > \text{ or } < c.
$$
When "$>$" the center is above the line and so more than half the area is above the line.

Comment: This sounds super easy, but I don't see it in my head.  Thanks for the quick reply, I'll plug in some numbers and figure it out.  Will mark as answer too.  Thanks.

Comment: I've got the center x,y but where'd a and b come from.  Is that the area of the two parts of the grid?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ and $c$ are the numbers you need to specify the line.

Comment: Oh okay.  Well I have the 4 corners and now the center, as well as the points x(t) and y(t) where the path intersects, but this is a bezier curve so I really don't have the line.

Comment: If you have any two of the points of intersection with the grid then you can find the equation of the line. If it's really a straight line then I don't see how Bezier curves come in.

Comment: Thanks Ethan.  The bezier is the entire line, but for purposes of the grid, we can just say the line is linear.  So I found the change in Y/change in X is my slope.  So is the slope now "c".  Jeezus I feel dumb.  I'm just hammering this in without learning but I only want to program :)

Comment: No. The slope is $-a/b$. You can just say your change in $y$ over change in $x$ is $a$ and set $b=1$. To find $c$ plug in $(x,y)$ for any point you know is on the line and solve for $c$.If you look up "linear equation" in something like Khan Academy your programming will go much faster.